# Converting a certificate from a .cer to .pem using powershell or .bat

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch, batch-file

I am trying to find a way to script converting a .cer formated cert to a .pem format either using powershell or cmdline native to windows. Does anyone have any idea how this might be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4691749/847990

Comment: PS does not have any native files, it would just be calling a program that has CLI ability.

Comment: Agree, use OpenSSL CLI....

Answer (score 6):

Run certutil -encode  .pem

You could also download the PSPKI module, and I think there is a cmdlet in there for this as well, but certutil is built into every single Windows machine since like Windows 2000.

Comment: example: `certutil -encode c:\in.cer c:\out.pem`